# PHP Get Values from POST Array

Tags: php, post

I'm processing a form that submits to my PHP page. The request data looks like this:

```
Array
(
[submission_id] => 363112875894117228
[name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Tom
        [1] => Jones
    )

[address] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21 Jump St
        [1] => 
        [2] => Sydney
        [3] => NSW
        [4] => 2000
        [5] => Australia
    )

[cellularnumber] => Array
    (
        [0] => (041) 234-5678
    )

)
```

I'm trying to set a variable that contains the value of the first name, last name etc. For example I would like to set a variable:

```
$firstName
```

that is equal to Tom.

I'm familiar with using this syntax:

```
$firstName = $_POST['name']
```

but not sure how to handle the array in this case?

Comment: $firstname=$_POST['name'][0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array index for name like

`$fname = $_POST['name'][0];
$lname = $_POST['name'][1];`

and use implode statement for the address like

`implode(" ",$_POST['address'])` (it will convert your address array to string)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this , I hope this should work for you.

```
$firstName = $_POST['name'][0];
$lastName = $_POST['name'][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a multidimensional array. In your case the array element name have one more sub array. You can access it as follows,

```
$firstName = $_POST['name'][0];
$lastName = $_POST['name'][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the whole array to JSON to POST using json_encode, then use json_decode to fetch all data at backend.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$result = json_encode(Array
(
'submission_id' => 363112875894117228,
'name' => Array
    (
        0 => 'Tom',
        1 => 'Jones',
    ),
'address' => Array
    (
        0 => '21 Jump St',
        1 => '',
        2 => 'Sydney',
        3 => 'NSW',
        4 => '2000',
        5 => 'Australia',
    ),
'cellularnumber' => Array
    (
        0 => '(041) 234-5678',
    ),
))
```

End up to {"submission_id":363112875894117228,"name":["Tom","Jones"],"address":["21 Jump St","","Sydney","NSW","2000","Australia"],"cellularnumber":["(041) 234-5678"]}